# External mapping configuration (no annotations) Java object to XML using CXF with REST web services

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, cxf, jax-rs

I need to customize the mapping of a Java beans to XML without modifying the object itself (cannot add annotations like @XmlRoolElement or @Transient). I m using CXF to expose REST web services.

Comment: How do you need to customize it? Why can't you modify the Java class? If your class is generated from an XSD, you could modify the XSD... Your requirements are quite vague and there is no real question

Comment: Couldn't be more clearer. If you want to know why its because there are many interfaces that expose these entities, each one in it own way, and not just XML. JSON too (this is achieved using Jackson Mixins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

> One of the latest CXF JAX-RS extensions allows users to provide
>   external models with the information which the runtime typically gets
>   from JAX-RS annotations like @Path, @PathParam, @Consumes, @Produces,
>   etc. There might be a number of cases when it can be advantageous to
>   describe how a given resource can be exposed as a RESTful service
>   without actually modifying this resource. For example, when new
>   dynamic interface implementations are registered, when no source code
>   can be modified, when the cost of future updates (for ex, modifying
>   the value of @Path annotations) is considered to be expensive, etc.

[Check the documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-advanced-features.html#JAX-RSAdvancedFeatures-RESTfulserviceswithoutannotations) .

**Update**

It might be better to use Aegis for your 
databinding and not JAXB (default databinding for cxf). [Check this part of documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/aegis-mapping-files.html) and [this part](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/aegis-databinding-20x.html) . 
And a [full example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-apachecxf/) by ibm

Comment: I believe this is for CXF service configuration annotations only. I need to externally configure the entity mappings